# How to load an Active Storage image into a canvas with a Stimulus controller?

Tags: asset-pipeline, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs

I would like to load the images that users submit into the Stimulus controller so that I can use it within my Three JS (3D JavaScript Library) code. How can I achieve this? I’ve already tried so many things and just can’t seem to pull it off.

The stack is Rails, esbuild/jsbundling-rails, Active Storage, Stimulus JS (and Three JS, but not really relevant for this question). I have a User and a Photos model with an has_one_attached :image, with a title(string).

My index.html.erb where all the instances of photo are available currently has a content tag:

```
<%= content_tag(:canvas, "", data: {controller: "threejs"}) %>
```

This is what that looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK2RG.jpg)

The image currently used is not in active storage, it’s bundled with esbuild and fingerprinted to come from the , which I did manually. At this point I don’t even want to know how to use multiple images attached to instances of Photo in my code - but rather just reference a single one.

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import GUI from 'lil-gui';
import TentImage from "../images/tent.png";

// Connects to data-controller="threejs"
export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    this.initThreeJS();
    this.loadTexture();
  }

  loadTexture() {
    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    textureLoader.load(TentImage, (texture) => { // TentImage will be replaced by the path to the digested image file created by esbuild.
      this.texture = texture; // Store the loaded texture in a variable so we can access it outside of this function
      this.rectangles.forEach((rectangle) => {
        rectangle.material.map = this.texture; // Assign the texture to the material of each rectangle
        rectangle.material.needsUpdate = true; // Telling Three.js that the material has been updated and that it needs to be re-rendered
      });
      console.log("Texture loaded!", texture);
    });
  }

  initThreeJS() {
    /** Debug */
    this.gui = new GUI();

    /** Scene, Camera, Renderer */
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xFFFFFF); // 0xFFFFFF = white
    this.sizes = {
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight
    }
    this.renderer.setSize( this.sizes.width, this.sizes.height );
    this.renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2)); // retina display - optimizing for performance, by creating a pixel ratio between own screens' and a maximum of 2
    document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

    /** Circle */
    const circleGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 2, 32 );
    this.wireframeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
      color: 0x00ff00,
      wireframe: true
    } );
    this.circle = new THREE.Mesh( circleGeometry, this.wireframeMaterial );

    // Rotate the circle around the X-axis by ~30 degrees
    this.circle.rotation.x = Math.PI / - 3;

    // To rotate around the Y-axis, uncomment:
    // this.circle.rotation.y = Math.PI / 4;

    /** Add Rectangles around the Circle */
    this.rectangles = this.addRectanglesToCircle(30, 2); // 8 rectangles, 2 of radius. Storing in a variable so we can access them outside the scope of this function (eg. for UI)
    this.loadTexture(); // Ensures that if the texture loads after the rectangles are created, it will be applied immediately

    /** Debug Variables */
    this.rectangles.forEach((rectangle) => {
      this.gui.add(rectangle.rotation, 'y').min(- 3).max(3).step(0.01).name('rotationY');
    });

    /** Grid & Axis Helper */
    this.gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper( 10, 10 );
    this.axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5); // 5 = represents the size (length) of the axes

    this.scene.add(
      this.gridHelper,
      this.circle,
      this.axesHelper);

    this.camera.position.z = 5;

    this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );

    /** Orbit Controls */
    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement); // needs to be renderer instead of canvas on Rails

    this.animate();
  }

  addRectanglesToCircle(numberOfRectangles, circleRadius) {
    const rectangleHeight = 0.5; // modifying the height of the rectangles
    const rectangleWidth = 1
    const rectangleGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(rectangleWidth, rectangleHeight);
    const rectangleMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      // color: 0xff0000, // Base color, visible if texture is not loaded
      side: THREE.DoubleSide, // ensures that the material renders on both sides of our 2D plane
      map: this.texture || null // Apply the texture if it's already loaded
    });
    const rectangles = []; // to store rectangles newly created, this is what gets called in the initThreeJS() function

    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfRectangles; i++) { // = we loop as many times as the number of rectangles we want to create
      const theta = (i / numberOfRectangles) * 2 * Math.PI; // angle between each rectangle
      const rectangle = new THREE.Mesh(rectangleGeometry, rectangleMaterial);

      // Position and rotation of each rectangle
      rectangle.position.x = circleRadius * Math.sin(theta);
      rectangle.position.y = circleRadius * Math.cos(theta);

      // Rectangle's rotation to face away from the circle's center
      rectangle.rotation.z = 0; // theta + Math.PI / 2 also a cool possibility, especially with rotation.y at 0.
      rectangle.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
      rectangle.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2 - theta;

      this.circle.add(rectangle); // Adding the rectangle as a child of the circle. This means that if we move or rotate the circle, the rectangles will follow its transformation as they're considered part of the circle in the scene hierarchy.
      rectangles.push(rectangle); // Adding the rectangle to the rectangles array, so that rectangles array can be accessed outside
    }
    return rectangles;
  }

  animate() {
    // This creates a loop that is causes the renderer to draw the scene every time the screen is refreshed (typically 60 times per second)
    requestAnimationFrame(this.animate.bind(this));

    // Render the scene with the camera
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you've found a solution for this but you can add the URL for the photo file (saved in ActiveStorage)

```rb
// view/template (erb)

        <%= content_tag :canvas, "", 
          data: {
            controller: "threejs",
            photo_image_url_value: url_for(@photo.image) # your Photo model's has_attached_image file
          }
        %>
```

Then in your stimulus controller, define that same `imageUrl` value so its callable in your jabbascrips like so:

```js
// app/javascripts/controllers/canvas_controller.js
export default class extends Controller {
  static values = { imageUrl: String };   
  // rest of your js...
```

You should be able to then grab that URL as:

```js
this.imageUrlValue
```

couple nice Videos as well here:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z5_Z4Hjfoc8
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VA19xZPCksQ